# Concatenate same selectors into single

Tags: css, intellij-idea, sass, less

When I have 2 same selectors in my scss file

```
.logo-black {
      background-color: #fff;
}

.logo-black {
    width: 10%;
}
```

is there some way to concatenate it into 1?

```
.logo-black {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Why not write it as one? Are you using somebody else's source code?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What is wrong with combining these two into one ?

Comment: you answered your question yourself, you can just do it like in your 2nd code snippet

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stylesheet compressor. For example, https://csscompressor.net/ with the compression level set to "standard (balance between readability and size)" will turn your first example into your second.

You could also fully minify your styles, and the beautify them. For example, using the above linked tool with the compression level set to "highest" will output

```
.logo-black{background-color:#fff;width:10%}
```

which you can then beautify with a CSS Beautifier - there are many, but for example http://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/ will turn that minified output into your second example.

Note that in all of these cases it's safest to work with your compiled CSS, not the source SCSS, since these formatting tools don't take the preprocessor's features into account.